# Array of objects in swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger-2.0

I am trying to define the swagger for below JSON response.

```
[
        {
            "STATE": [
                {
                    "CODE_NM": "A&B",
                    "CODE_DSC": "Argyll & Bute",
                    "CODE_ID": 123
                },
                {
                    "CODE_NM": "AA",
                    "CODE_DSC": "sd",
                    "CODE_ID": 12345
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "COUNTRY": [
                {
                    "CODE_NM": "sd",
                    "CODE_DSC": "CAN",
                    "CODE_ID": 12
                },
                {
                    "CODE_NM": "AA",
                    "CODE_DSC": "USA",
                    "CODE_ID": 12345
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

My swagger definition is something like below.

```
`responses:
        '200':
          description: ''
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/searchTypeResp'
definitions:
  codeTable:
    title: codeTable
    type: object
    properties:
      CODE_NM:
        type: string
      CODE_DSC:
        type: string
      CODE_ID:
        type: string
    required:
    - CODE_NM
    - CODE_ID
  searchTypeResp:
    title: searchTypeResp
    type: object
    properties:
      COUNTRY:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/codeTable'
        example:
        - CODE_NM: 1
          CODE_DSC: Sherlock
          CODE_ID: 1
        - CODE_NM: 1
          CODE_DSC: Sherlock
          CODE_ID: 2
      STATE:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/codeTable'
`
```

Above definition is yielding the response like below which is wrong for my requirement.

```
  [
      {
        "COUNTRY": [
          {
            "CODE_NM": 1,
            "CODE_DSC": "Sherlock",
            "CODE_ID": 1
          },
          {
            "CODE_NM": 1,
            "CODE_DSC": "Sherlock",
            "CODE_ID": 2
          }
        ],
        "STATE": [
          {
            "CODE_NM": "string",
            "CODE_DSC": "string",
            "CODE_ID": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Can anyone please help to get to the correct definition? I need the swagger definition that suits the json I posted above.

Comment: Are "COUNTRY" and "STATE" fixed property names, or can they be arbitrary strings?

Comment: I have 8 different strings that can be in place of "COUNTRY or "STATE" . Ideally this should be a string with enum values.